# Image file is not loading properly

Tags: javascript, image, background, html5-canvas, png

Using Javascript Canvas and HTML5

I've loaded about 100 backgrounds all in the same manner but this one particular background, even though it has the correct name with no spaces and the same code as other backgrounds, refuses to load in-game for some reason, and it's frustrating.

The Code That Fails:
    `document.getElementById('currentBackground').src = "assets/visual/ROOM_102/ROOM_102_16_C.png";`

Similar code that works:
    `document.getElementById('currentBackground').src = "assets/visual/ROOM_102/ROOM_102_16_B.png";`

in the directory:

```
    ROOM_102_16_A.png
    ROOM_102_16_B.png
    ROOM_102_16_C.png
    ROOM_102_16_D.png
```

All code for camera_16:

```
    if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_102_16') {
        if (document.getElementById('sprayPurchased').innerText === 'FALSE') {
            document.getElementById('currentBackground').src = "assets/visual/ROOM_102/ROOM_102_16_A.png";
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById('sprayPurchased').innerText === 'TRUE' &&
            document.getElementById('mysteryPurchased').innerText === 'FALSE') {
            document.getElementById('currentBackground').src = "assets/visual/ROOM_102/ROOM_102_16_B.png";
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById('mysteryPurchased').innerText === 'TRUE' &&
            document.getElementById("sequence1").innerText === 'INCOMPLETE') {
            document.getElementById('currentBackground').src = "assets/visual/ROOM_102/ROOM_102_16_C.png";
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById("sequence1").innerText === 'COMPLETE') {
            document.getElementById('currentBackground').src = "assets/visual/ROOM_102/ROOM_102_16_D.png";
        }
    }
```

In the index.html:
`<img id="currentBackground">`

I had a similar problem with camera_07 when I changed the name from ROOM_102_07.png to ROOM_102_07_A.png; the background png for camera_07 started working again by inserting a single newline of whitespace *shrugs* but no such luck with camera_16

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by exiting the NetBeans IDE and restarting it. Now the background loads properly.